# Rails: Sub-routing. No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have custom CRUD routes for example - for profiles

```
get '/profiles', to: 'profiles#index'
  get '/profiles/new', to: 'profiles#new', :as => 'new_profile'
  post '/profiles', to: 'profiles#create'
  get '/profiles/edit/:id', to: 'profiles#edit', :as => 'profile'
  patch '/profiles/edit/:id', to: 'profiles#update'
  get '/profiles/get_profiles', to: 'profiles#get_profiles'
```

It works okay. But I do the same routing for profile skills, which is under relation of profile. Routes of ProfileSkills looks like this

```
get '/profiles/:profile_id/profile_skills', to: 'profile_skills#index'
  get '/profiles/:profile_id/profile_skills/new', to: 'profile_skills#new', :as => 'new_profile_skill'
  post '/profiles/:profile_id/profile_skills', to: 'profile_skills#create'
  get '/profiles/:profile_id/profile_skills//edit/:id', to: 'profile_skills#edit', :as => 'profile_skills'
  patch '/profiles/:profile_id/profile_skills/edit/:id', to: 'profiles#update'
```

When I under the route for creating the new item

```
http://localhost:3000/profiles/1/profile_skills/new
```

It throw an exception

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"profile_skills", :profile_id=>"1"}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

On form for line

```
  <%= form_for @profile_skill do |form| %>
```

Why he don't understand that I'm under the 'new' route and it looking for 'edit', when I'm under the 'new'?
This problem is only when I'm on sub-routes. In 'Profile' routes for example, if works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes use this

```
resources :profiles do
  resources :profile_skills
end
```

this will provide you the routes like this

`profiles/:profile_id/profile_skill` points to `index` action of profile_skill
   `profiles/:profile_id/profile_skill/new` points to `new` action of profile_skill
`profiles/:profile_id/profile_skill/:profile_skill_id` points to `show` action of profile_skill
`profiles/:profile_id/profile_skill/:profile_skill_id/edit` points to `edit` action of profile_skill

and so on.

for more help visit [Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: I know that this is solution, but I try do not use 'resources' ( just for fully understand what happens in routing ) . I just bring only 'form' line out of common form file and set custom url for each form. It was just interesting how form understand, this is create or update page. I thought it looks at the end of routing for 'new' or 'edit', but now I think that is something different logic. Anyway, Thank You!